# UITableView Header Background Color without Xamarin.Forms

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I want to change the backgroundcolor of the Headerlines in my UITableView.

I've tried the following:
1: Set on Xcode-Designer in "TableView" -> "Section Index" -> "Background"
2: As Code in ViewDidLoad: TableView.TintColor = UIColor.Black and TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;

Nothing happened, the Background is still Light Gray..

Everything I find here was with Xamarin.Forms, but i'm not using Xamarin.Forms!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own custom views and override method `GetViewForHeader`. You can refer to the following code,which could change the Header Background Color and text color:

```
public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    UIView view = new UIView();
    view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
    view.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 100, 200, 50);

    UILabel label = new UILabel();
    label.Frame = view.Bounds;
    label.Text = "test";
    label.TextColor = UIColor.Red;

    view.Add(label);

    return view;
}
```